# Python generic method scope

Tags: python

I've got a class that wraps functions with some metadata, in particular a parental relationship with other instances:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, func, parent):
        self.func = func
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent_func = self.parent.func
```

In a few cases, I would like to use `Foo` to wrap a function that internally calls another Foo's function:

```
def f(x): return str(x).title()
def g(x): return self.parent_func(x)
a = Foo(f)
b = Foo(g, a)
print b.func("april is the cruellest month")
>>> April Is The Cruellest Month
```

Problem is that `g` isn't actually a method until `b` runs `Foo.__init__`, so it doesn't have a self.

I'm assuming there's something rather fundamental I'm missing about scoping, object methods, or functions' first-class citizenship status, and would greatly appreciate a point in the right direction.

---

EDIT: Looks like my above genericized example threw folks off, so I'm adding a more specific example below. The idea of this class is that each instance is an integer property (primality, perfection, its list of factors, etc), and contains a function that tests an integer for the property (returning a bool or an answer, as the case base be).

```
def f(n): # returns list of factors of n
def s(n): return len(self.parent_func(n))==2 # checks if n is semiprime

factors = Foo(f)
semiprime = Foo(s, factors)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your question boils down to "how can I dynamically add a method to an object", the the short answer is don't do it (1). Objects can have attributes which can be functions, and that's fine, but these functions do not become methods and don't behave like methods. For example if `foo.attr is sum` then `foo.attr(x)` is the same as `sum(x)` not `sum(foo, x)`.

Your question has a certain functional "aroma" to it, if you wanted to drop the class/object stuff and go the fully functional route you could do something like this:

```
def identity(x):
    return x

def f(n):
    return [i for i in range(1, 10) if (n % i == 0)]

def s(factors):
    return (len(factors) == 2)

def foo(func, helper=identity):
    def innerfunc(n):
        return func(helper(n))
    return innerfunc

a = foo(f)
print a(6)
# [1, 2, 3, 6]
b = foo(s, a)
print b(5)
# True
```

If that doesn't appeal to you, I would suggest thinking of the `func` and `parent` attributes on your `Foo` class as data attached to your objects, not as methods, and work out the problem from there. The logic associated with your class should live inside proper methods. These methods can refer to the data as needed. Here's my very simple example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, func, parent=None):
        self.func = func
        self.parent = parent

    def run(self, n):
        if self.parent is None:
            return self.func(n)
        else:
            return self.func(self.parent.run(n))

a = Foo(f)
print a.run(6)
# [1, 2, 3, 6]
b = Foo(s, a)
print b.run(5)
# True
```

(1) Methods belong to a class not an object, so the question should really be how can I attach something to my object that behaves like a method.

Comment: Hi Bi Rico: Thanks very much for this detailed response. You both identified what I was misunderstanding (methods belong to classes not instances) and the deeper issue that was leading to that misunderstanding (mixing functional programming habits into my OOP).

Answer (score 0):

As Matthew said, "parental relationship" would point to inheritance. But if you want/have to do it this way, you could use [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial


class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, func, parent=None):
        self.func = partial(func, self)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent_func = self.parent.func if parent is not None else None


def f(self, x):
    return str(x).title()


def g(self, x):
    return self.parent_func(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = Foo(f)
    b = Foo(g, a)

    print b.func("april is the cruellest month")
```

Answer (score -3):

When you call a object method, it is called with self as first parameter.

```
def f(self,x): return str(x).title()
def g(self,x): return self.parent_func(x)
```